# Jquery Mobile same background within the same file with multiple <div data role=page>

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I made a jquery mobile page with multiple `data-role=page` divs to navigate within the page.

The problem is that I need to keep the same background picture that does not refresh or move when I navigate within the page.

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the default background from the pseudo page elements and then add your custom background to the `body` element. This can be done with CSS:

```
.ui-mobile .ui-page {
    background : transparent;
}
body {
    background : url(...);
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/feZJ7/2/

This will apply the same background for all pages. You can just target the `.ui-mobile .ui-page` elements with CSS to change their backgrounds respectively.