# jQueryMobile Change Background image

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, razor, background-image

Does someone knows how to change and/or set a background image for a jQueryMobile-built site?
Cause I tried everything (not so much,actually) I found, but I really can't overwrite the default css for jquery mobile (http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css) adding my own one.
Hope for your help,
thanks!

---

SOLVED: in your CSS file, you have to override the jQuery Mobile ".ui-mobile .type-home .ui-content".
That's how I did it:

```
.ui-mobile .type-home .ui-content { 
    background: white url(Image/A-HD.jpg); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50% 80%; /*50% 80% mozilla optimized*/ 
    background-attachment: fixed; 
    background-size: 50%; /*50% mozilla optimized */ 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Mobile same background within the same file with multiple <div data role=page>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320235/jquery-mobile-same-background-within-the-same-file-with-multiple-div-data-role). There are several answers on Stack Overflow that can help you. Please do some research before asking questions as most of your questions have most likely been asked and answered before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the (a?) problem:
I had to override `.ui-mobile .type-home .ui-content`
and inside that I can put all the properties I want.
Hope it can helps someone!

Comment: Here you are:

.ui-mobile .type-home .ui-content  
{
    background: white url(Image/A-HD.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 80%;  /*50% 80% mozilla optimized*/
    background-attachment: fixed; 
    background-size: 50%; /*50% mozilla optimized */
}

That's how I changed my jQuery Mobile site background. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
.ui-page{
    background:url("../../Images/your.png") no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

This code has worked for me in the past.